# Android - Firestore/Firebase Realtime Database ".info/connected" returns wrong connection state

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I use Firestore Beta in my app and I'd like to check if there is a working online connection to the Firestore Database. The documentation says that currently there is no direct way to query the connection state, but one can use the Firebase connection state as a workaround. The code snippet for that can also be found in this part of the documentation: [Build presence in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).

```
    connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    connectionStateListener = connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);

            if (connected == null) {
                changeState(FirebaseConnectionState.error);
                return;
            }

            if (connected) {
                changeState(FirebaseConnectionState.connected);
            } else {
                changeState(FirebaseConnectionState.not_connected);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            L.i("FirebaseConnectionStateListener was cancelled");
        }
    });
```

The `ValueEventListener` itself is working and I get status updates. But for some reason the status switches from "connected" to "not connected" after 1 minute. Besides this being incorrect, I am not able to get it back to "connected" except restarting the app.

Here's some debug output:

```
2018-11-15 13:38:20.340: [FirebaseHeartbeatConnector] FirebaseHeartbeatConnector() called with: firebaseApp = [FirebaseApp{name=development, options=FirebaseOptions{applicationId=1:xxxxx:android:xxxxx, apiKey=xxxxx, databaseUrl=null, gcmSenderId=null, storageBucket=xxxx.appspot.com, projectId=xxxxx}}]
2018-11-15 13:38:20.480: [FirebaseHeartbeatConnector] startConnecting() called
2018-11-15 13:38:20.482: [FirebaseHeartbeatConnector] doSendFirestoreHeartbeatRequest() called
2018-11-15 13:38:20.840: [FirebaseHeartbeatConnector] change State called
2018-11-15 13:38:20.840: [FirebaseHeartbeatConnector] State changed initial -> not_connected
2018-11-15 13:38:21.380: [FirebaseHeartbeatConnector] change State called
2018-11-15 13:38:21.381: [FirebaseHeartbeatConnector] State changed not_connected -> connected
2018-11-15 13:39:20.514: [FirebaseHeartbeatConnector] change State called
2018-11-15 13:39:20.515: [FirebaseHeartbeatConnector] State changed connected -> not_connected
```

Why is that and how can I get a correct status update?

Comment: On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no pending write or `onDisconnect` operations, and is not explicitly disconnected by the `goOffline` method, Firebase closes the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity. Read more on the [Detecting Connection State](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) documentation.

Comment: If you're not using the Firebase Realtime Database for anything else but connection state, you might need to add an empty connection listener. Can you try if adding `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().keepSynced(true);` makes a difference?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen good idea, but this throws an DatabaseException: Can't call keepSynced() on .info paths.

Comment: @Grimthorr thanks for the hint! Didn't read that part. Too bad though...seems like the best solution is a normal online-check then. thanks for your help guys!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Should this caveat be added to the [Build presence in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence#solution_cloud_functions_with_realtime_database) documentation? It does seem unreliable to use Realtime Database for presence if you're not actively using it otherwise?

Comment: btw. my colleague is implementing the same on iOS and there is no 1 minute hang-up time to see.

Comment: @FlorianMeyer It might work better if you're using a Service to check connection state and/or making real use of Realtime Database listeners, but otherwise a [connectivity status monitor](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring) might work better. As for iOS, you're right, as the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) doesn't include the same note about closing the connection after 60 seconds, which makes the behavour inconsistent.

Comment: @Grimthorr If what I asked fixes the problem, then indeed it needs to be updated in the documentation.

Comment: @FlorianMeyer So don't call it on `.info` path. ;-) I actually meant it on `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().keepSynced(true);`. Since you're not using the Realtime Database for anything real, this sync of the entire database just creates an empty listener which might keep the connection alive.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Aha, I didn't realise `keepSynced(true)` created an empty listener, that's a neat little trick and saves having to create one manually. I just tested this and using just `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().keepSynced(true);` does indeed stop it from disconnecting after 60 seconds.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen could you have a look on my gist? When using `.getReference().keepSynced(true)` I get no callback at all to the ValueEventListener. https://gist.github.com/fm-eb/d629a7e236a0066624696c9561aaf8ab we can also contiue to discuss on the gist. I will publish the result here in the end.

Comment: The `keepSynced` call in your gist should not affect the other listener on that same ref. I'm not sure why that would make a difference. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be caused by Firebase closing the connection due to inactivity, which only happens on Android. From the [Detecting Connection State](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) documentation:

> On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no pending write or `onDisconnect` operations, and is not explicitly disconnected by the `goOffline` method, Firebase closes the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity.

Because your app isn't making real use of the Realtime Database (you're using Cloud Firestore instead), there won't be any other write operations or other listeners attached, so the connection is closed automatically. You'll likely see something like the below in logcat:

> ```
> V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
> ```

As a possible workaround, you could try attaching a listener to any node in the Realtime Database to keep the connection alive (anything will do, even if it doesn't actually exist):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("keepalive").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // Do nothing - this listener just keeps the connection alive
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Log.i("Keepalive listener was cancelled");
    }
});
```

Alternatively, as suggested by [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen), you can trick Firebase into hanging onto the connection by telling it to keep the entire Realtime Database synced, using [`keepSynced()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache) on an empty reference:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().keepSynced(true);
```

You'll need to remember to remove the keepalive listener or undo `keepSynced()` when you actually want to mark the user's presence as disconnected, though.

Finally, with both of these examples, you still need to attach and make use of the [`.info/connected` connection state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) to handle changes in connection state:

> For many presence-related features, it is useful for your app to know when it is online or offline. Firebase Realtime Database provides a special location at `/.info/connected` which is updated every time the Firebase Realtime Database client's connection state changes. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
> connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
>   @Override
>   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
>     boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
>     if (connected) {
>       System.out.println("connected");
>     } else {
>       System.out.println("not connected");
>     }
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
>     System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: I tried this, but the valueeventlistener does not receive any callback. I made a gist for further discussion: https://gist.github.com/fm-eb/d629a7e236a0066624696c9561aaf8ab

Comment: That's because nothing exists in your Realtime Database; this listener is just needed to keep the connection alive. You'll still need to use the `.info/connected` listener in your original question.

Comment: The best method is to use `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().keepSynced(true);` which stops the connection from timing out. Again, you'll still need to attach the `.info/connected` listener to actually monitor the connection status.

Comment: hi, i commented on the gist. Event without this change, I still get the 60 seconds timeout.

Comment: (1/2) That' really strange. I copy/pasted your code and it worked once. Then I added my firebaseapp-instance as paramter for FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() and it didn't work anymore (1 minute timeout). Then I removed the firebaseapp-instance and it also didn't work anymore...
Then I completely uninstalled the app and went back to your code again => does not work anymore....

Comment: (2/2) i have no idea what's going on there and unfortunately I have no time left to play around with it. So I will implement a normal online-check using the CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE.
Thank you for your time and effort trying to figure this out!! I hope the documentation will improve on this topic.