# Firestore + Realtime Database: presence comes to offline after a minute and never turn back online

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I build application with firestore, react-native and react-native-firestore. Now I use only firestore in my project. I want to implement presence for that app, and found solution: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence?authuser=0

I started by writing simple code:

```
firebase.database().ref(".info/connected").on("value", snap => {
  console.log(".info/connected", snap.val());
});
```

just to test how it works.

It outputs this

```
11-21 14:48:03.117  6502  6571 I ReactNativeJS: '.info/connected', false
11-21 14:48:03.710  6502  6571 I ReactNativeJS: '.info/connected', true
11-21 14:49:02.892  6502  6571 I ReactNativeJS: '.info/connected', false
```

As you can see, right after application startup, connected status becomes `true` within a second. But after ~1 minute, it becomes `false` and never goes back to `true`. Meanwhile application is fully operate, queries sent to firestore succesfully finished and etc.

I think it happens because I actually do not perform any query to Realtime Database. Am I right?

Comment: You are correct: if you don't listen for any other data, the Firebase SDK will auto-close its connection to the Realtime Database after a minute. To prevent this, add a separate listener to the root of the empty database, for example by calling `firebase.database().ref().keepSynced(true)`. This is a known issue in the documentation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53320480/android-firestore-firebase-realtime-database-info-connected-returns-wrong-c

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the Logic for realTime Database, an then you need use CloudFunctions to keep Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore in sync. it is the only way. have you ever used cloud functions in the past?

Comment: No, I build slightly different case, and I do not need the whole power of presence. I want to indicate end user that connection is lost (and remove indicator when connection restores).

Comment: but internet connection do you mean?

Comment: Not only internet connection - connection to firebase servers. Becuase internet connection is generally available, but firebase servers may be not reachable.